# Xubuntu splash hangs on boot for 15s

Tags: boot, 13.04, xubuntu, plymouth

Problem started recently. When I log in (in 80% of cases), the spinning logo on blue background hangs (wheel doesn't spin) for around 15s. Afterwards, the login box shows normally.

What's interesting is that if I try to login in `tty2` while it's stuck, the login also stucks for a while after entering password and showing the `Welcome to Ubuntu` message.

EDIT: Could it be connected with the fact that my audio stopped working recently? No big update, but all of a sudden, only `Dummy output` is shown. Dunno whether a "small" kernel update was released.

```
petr@sova:~$ uname -a
Linux sova 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it could a small problem in a recent update/upgrade. So long as it doesn't cause any serious problems other than a slightly longer delay and some strange screen-jitsu, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Try updating/upgrading, that might fix it, otherwise, just wait and see if it pans out on its own.

Comment: No problem. I don't think it could be related, but, who knows! Like I said, unless it is really bothering you/causing real problems, just let it pan out, hopefully an update will fix it.